# Removing inline styles from html string

Tags: javascript

I'm getting data from Wordpress, which contains HTML with inline styles. Before I insert this HTML into my React website, I would like to remove all inline styles. For example, I get something like:

```
<div style='height: 500px'>
<img  style='height: 300px; width: 250px'/>
... more elements with inline styles
</div>
```

I'm looking for a clean way of doing this because I've tried using other solutions on SO and they use Jquery and other JS methods which would not work since I'm using React to build my website.

Answer (score 2):

You call select all the html tags and using `document.querySelectorAll('*')` and iterate through each one of them and using `removeAttribute`, removes `style` attribute.

```js
const htmlString = `<div style='height: 500px'>
<img  style='height: 300px; width: 250px'/>
<p> text</p>
<div style="color: red">Red text</div>
... more elements with inline styles
</div>`;
const htmlNode = document.createElement('div');
htmlNode.innerHTML = htmlString;
htmlNode.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
    node.removeAttribute('style');
});
console.log(htmlNode.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all tag in your body then use `removeAttribute` to remove style attribute.

```js
function remove(){

   var allBodyTag = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

   for (var i = 0; i < allBodyTag.length; i++) {
       allBodyTag[i].removeAttribute("style");
   }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="remove()">Remove </button>
<div style='height: 500px'>
This is text
<img  style='height: 50px; width: 250px'/>
</div>
```